Rust leak checking with heaptrack on Raspberry
I'm trying to check memory leaks on my Rust app with heaptrack.
To do this I simply run the debug version of my app with heaptrack and I can see all data:

But I need to test my app on a Raspberry Pi 4 (with Ubuntu).
In the Raspy I have recompiled the same application in developmnet, just changing the Rust toolchain (stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu).
But running heaptrack on the Raspy version does not give any useful info: 
Note:

the app is compiled in develop mode
Tried to install additional debug Symbols packages but nothing changed
Raspy OS version: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
The App in raspy with heaptrack starts and works ok, does not crash

What I'm missing?

I don't know, but you should be aware of this portable alternative that profiles the heap from within the Rust executable.

Thank you @FinnBear for the suggestion, I'll give it a try!
